# Contador Javascript de clicks

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Suponhamos que eu tenha o seguinte contador:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
    Curtir <span class="badge"> 4 </span>
</button>
```

quero aplicar esse codigo abaixo:

```
function criaCounter(init) {
    var count = init || 0;
    return function() {
        count++;
        alert(count);
    }
}

$('#addCount').click(criaCounter(5));
```

de maneira que não emita um alerta e sim aumente o numero ao lado do botão de curtir, sempre somando infinitamente td vez que alguem clicar.

Comment: Existe só um unico `<span class="badge"> 4 </span>` na página?

Comment: Verdade, bem lembrado. são varios na pagina, cada postagem nova um contador 0 zerado com o botão curtir começa. to pesando em usar o do faceboo mesmo.

Comment: Ok, se há vários é preciso ter isso em conta. Vou dar uma resposta também, mas ainda não sei o que é o `'#addCount'`... podes explicar a ideia? é para mostrar a contagem?

Answer (score 6):

Pode pegar o número com [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) e acrescentar +1 a cada clique. Sempre substituindo o `textContent`.

```js
var contador = document.querySelector('.badge');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var numero = parseInt(contador.textContent) + 1;
  contador.textContent = numero;
});
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
  Curtir <span class="badge"> 4 </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Acho que vale a pena explicar que nesta resposta estás a sugerir uma abordagem diferente onde não usas o código do AP.

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer assim:

```
function criaCounter(init) {
    var count = init || 0;
    return function() {
       count++;
       var badges = document.getElementsByClassName("badge");
       for (var i in badges) {
          badges[i].innerHTML = count;
       }
   }
}

$('#addCount').click(criaCounter(5));
```